# Settings for GeoServer: large WMS png request failing

Tags: geoserver, centos

We recently upgraded from GeoServer 2.1 to the 2.5-SNAPSHOT, both from official OsGeo Centos packages, git revision, c7886eb21885c88d40029432c3178f88931ed820

We are getting the dreaded:

> Rendering process failed
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   Java heap space

errors on processing. The WMS png image we are requesting is 2600 x 2600 pixels and worked on the older version of GeoServer. If we reduce the width/height below 2000 x 2000 pixels, the image is returned. This would seem to imply some cutoff at  around 15Mb, assuming 3/4 bytes per pixel, and 4 million pixels at 2000 x 2000.

We have tried setting the config variable `<maxRequestMemory>50000</maxRequestMemory>` in **web.xml** in the Geoserver config directory as suggested in [the docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/configuration.html).

We have also tried setting `Xmx` via `JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx768m"` in **/etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf** as suggested in [the docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/container.html).

Running,

```
ps ax|grep tomcat
```

yields

> /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx768m -Djavax.sql.DataSource.Factory=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms256m -Xmx768m -Xrs -XX:PerfDataSamplingInterval=500 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.geotools.referencing.forceXY=true -DGEOEXPLORER_DATA=/var/lib/opengeo/geoexplorer -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx768m -Djavax.sql.DataSource.Factory=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms256m -Xmx768m -Xrs -XX:PerfDataSamplingInterval=500 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.geotools.referencing.forceXY=true -DGEOEXPLORER_DATA=/var/lib/opengeo/geoexplorer -classpath :/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat6/temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

which shows 768m for Xmx, which should be vastly in excess of the requirements for a 2600x2600 pixel png. This is against a dev server with no other users or requests against it. Clearly we are missing something.

Comment: depends on how many features in the layers you are trying to draw and how many featurestyles there are in the slds for each layer. It can be 3 or 4 times the number of features for a road layer (i.e. with casing) then multiply by the number of layers by the pixel size.

Comment: @iant. So, you are saying each object type within an SLD is rendered independently and then they are stacked? We are dealing with OS Mastermap here, so there are a lot of styles involved, albeit only one db table and one SLD. Am I changed the correct variables, maxRequestMemory and Xmx. I have already more than doubled both, and the request works at 2305 pixels and falls over at 2306, which makes me think something else is afoot.

Comment: It's not dependent on the number of layers, but on the max number of FeatureTypeStyle you have for a single layer, since GS will allocate a drawing surface for each one of them. Also, the error makes me think it's not GS own memory control, but a real out of memory happening in the JVM, so something else (parallel requests maybe) is chewing memory there

Comment: @AndreaAime.  Thanks, but as I said, it is a dev box and I am the only user and this the only request, so parallel requests unlikely cause. As soon as this goes above 2305 x 2305 pixels it blows up and I have already doubled settings listed above.  There must be another setting we are missing.

Comment: Tomcat7 might also be worth a try, since you're upgrading anyway, right.